# preg_replace remove [] around array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, json

I currently have an array that looks like this:

```
    [[{"name":"Shirt","data":[1,1,5,5,1,10000]},{"name":"Skittles","data":[1,9,1,1]}]]
```

I'm using:

```
        preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:',json_encode($results));
```

to create an array that should look like this:

```
    [{"name":"Shirt","data":[1,1,5,5,1,10000]},{"name":"Skittles","data":[1,9,1,1]}]
```

However I can't seem to get rid of the extra set of brackets.

My model:

```
    function get_data()
   {
$this->db->select('ItemName, QuantitySold');
$query = $this->db->get('transactions');

$results = array();

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    if(!isset($results[$row['ItemName']]))
        $results[$row['ItemName']] = array('name' => $row['ItemName'], 'data' => array());
    $results[$row['ItemName']]['data'][] = $row['QuantitySold'];
}

//Rekey arrays so they aren't associative
$results = array_values($results);
return $results;
```

}

My controller:

```
    function test()
{
    $this->load->model('data');
    $series_data[] = $this->data->get_data();
    $data['series_data'] = json_encode($series_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:',json_encode($series_data));
    $this->load->view('chart', $data);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: the two strings are clearly not related

Comment: Sorry, I just put the second one in for formatting. I'll edit it for less confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use preg_replace.... this is simply json encoded data:

```
$string = '[[{"name":"Shirt","data":[1,1,5,5,1,10000]},{"name":"Skittles","data":[1,9,1,1]}]]';
var_dump(
    json_encode(
        json_decode($string)[0]
    )
);
```

Comment: I keep getting an array to string conversiona error. I'll put in all my code for better help

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Instead of `preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:',json_encode($series_data));` simply do `json_encode($series_data[0]);`.... or even earlier: use `$series_data = $this->data->get_data();
` instead of `$series_data[] = $this->data->get_data();`